# Command prompt opening multiple windows on wshShell.Run

Tags: windows, vba, command, prompt

Hi I'm trying to run following command in VBA

Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
wshShell.Run "cmd.exe runas some commands"

It's opening multiple command prompt windows.

If I run
wshShell.Run "cmd.exe" 
Only this then it opens a single window.

Am i doing anything wrong in the 1st scenario.

Comment: do you mean like 
`Set wshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")`

`wshShell.Run "cmd.exe /K echo ""Hello World"""`

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The issue got resolved earlier. Actually i was opening cmd promt through vba by clicking on a button and then passing {enter} command to cmd. The problem was when I was cicking on the button it was taking some time to open cmd promt and due to that the enter command that i was supposed to pass to the cmd was getting passed to the same button itself and it was again opening new cmd promt and it was getting stuck in infinite loop. I added application.wait in the code and it solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the /K switch and keep the quotes aroung cmd.exe before you run the rest of your commands

wshShell.Run " 'cmd.exe /K' 'commands here'"